# Visual Studio Indicator/Icon

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Can someone tell me what this is?  Also, how did I get it there?  Thanks!

[image: indicator]

Answer (score 3):

The first is a "find" indicator. (I don't know the actual technical term.) When you do a "quick find " or "search" your code for a particular term this indicator shows up on the line where the term was found.

As far as the second one I believe indicates a change in the code. When you make a change to the line it will turn a different color, then when you save the file it will turn green. Again I am not sure of the technical term.

Answer (score 1):

The green line indicates a change that you have made since you last opened the file that has been saved already. It's yellow before saving. I don't know about the other one.

Answer (score 1):

The green/yellow part shows a map of your source file. The green part changes to yellow when you've made changes to those lines.

(edit) I don't know about the other one, but it looks like it could be the next step in execution?

Comment: the other line might be the line index of the whole file.